# sqoop export avro nested record AvroExportMapper

Tags: avro, sqoop, sqoop2

given an avro record schema for RecordA as

```
"type":"record"...
"fields": [ { "name": "typeB", "type":"RecordB"} ...
```

and RecordB avro record as

```
"type":"record"
"fields": [ {"name": "mysqoopfield", "type":"int" } ...
```

is there a mechanism in sqoop-export by which I can export the value of mysqoopfield to RDBMS with a table with just column mysqoofield ?

have tried

```
sqoop-export --connect ... --driver ... --export /path/to/avro --columns typeB.mysqoopfield | typeB[mysqoopfield]
```

which don't work. the . is translated to a '_' by the AvroExportMapper. Just ondering if this is supported before digging further ?
Doesn't also seem like a custom mapper implemenation can be provided to sqoop ?